# Mercadopago api create payment custom taxes

Tags: mercadopago

When trying to create a mercadopago payment with custom taxes value, setting the taxes array is not enough, it gives the folloging error:

> Net and Tax amounts can't be null

Bad request, bad_request error code 400

```php
<?php

$client->post("/v1/payments", [
           'transaction_amount' => 130000,
           'taxes' => [
               [
                   'type' => 'IVA',
                   'value' => 0
               ]
           ],
           'description' => 'order description',
           'payment_method_id' => 'baloto',
           'payer' => [
               'email' => $cart->email
           ],
           'external_reference' => $payment->reference,
           "callback_url" => config('services.mercadopago.back_urls.success')
       ])
```

What is missing in the params?

Answer (score 1):

When using custom taxes additionally to the taxes array you need to add the "net_amount" param, as follows:

```php
<?php

$client->post("/v1/payments", [
           'transaction_amount' => 130000,
           'net_amount' => 130000,
           'taxes' => [
               [
                   'type' => 'IVA',
                   'value' => 0
               ]
           ],
           'description' => 'order description',
           'payment_method_id' => 'baloto',
           'payer' => [
               'email' => $cart->email
           ],
           'external_reference' => $payment->reference,
           "callback_url" => config('services.mercadopago.back_urls.success')
       ])
```